# jQuery templates fundamentals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I've got two items in a data object which should subsitute two expressions within my html file. However this is somehow not working. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        var source   = $("#template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var data = {
            title:"The Earth seen from Apollo 11",
            author:"Ed g2s",
            };
        var html    = template(data);
    </script>
    <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h3>{{author}}</h3>
    </script></body>
```

Comment: Your first script is not actually `type="text/x-handlebars-template"`.

Comment: Thanks! that worked! =P

Comment: I've also defined where the HTML data would be inserted by setting an empty content div.